# How to check for the presence of multiple strings for each value of a particular column in R Dataframe?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, boolean, boolean-logic

How do we identify all those row entries in a particular column that contain a specific set of keywords?

For example, I have the following dataframe:

```
test <- data.frame(nom = 1:5, name = c("ser bla", "onlybla", "inspectiongfa serdafds", "inspection", "serbla blainspection"))
```

[image]

My keywords of interest are **"ser"** & **"inspection"**

What I'm looking for is to enlist all the values of the second column (i.e. *name*) in which both the keywords are present together.

So basically, my output should enlist the *name* values of rows 3 and 4 viz. **"inspectiongfa serdafds"** & **"serbla blainspection"**

---

What I have tried is the following:

I first generate a truth table to enlist the presence of each of the keywords for each row in the dataframe as follows:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(c("ser", "inspection"), grepl, test$name))
```

[image]

Once I get this, all I have to do is identify all those row entries where the values are a pair of **TRUE TRUE**. Hence, they'll correspond to the cases where the keywords of interest are present. Here it's the same rows 3 & 4.

But, I'm not able to figure out how to identify such row entries with the TRUE TRUE pair and whether this whole process is a bit of an overkill and it can be done in a much efficient manner.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there :)

Here's a solution extending what you have done:

```
# store your logic test outcomes
conditions_df <- as.data.frame(sapply(c("ser", "inspection"), grepl, test$name))

# False=0 & True=1. Can use rowSums to get the total and find ones that =2 ie True+True
# which gives you the indices of the TRUE outcomes ie the rows we need to filter test
locate_rows <- which(rowSums(conditions_df) == 2)
test$name[locate_rows]
[1] "inspectiongfa serdafds"
[2] "serbla blainspection"
```